# waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS/Bluetooth HAT gps software problems (AT commands)

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w-2

when I got the hat working with the serial communication I have a problem. it seems that the GPSObj not stores the values
when I running the test codes for the gps data ex:
Code: Select all

```
from gsmHat import GSMHat, SMS, GPS
import time

gsm = GSMHat('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)

GPSObj = gsm.GetActualGPS()

print('Latitude: %s' % str(GPSObj.Latitude))<br>
print('Longitude: %s' % str(GPSObj.Longitude))<br>
print('Altitude: %s' % str(GPSObj.Altitude))<br>
```

It just returning:

```
Latitude: 0.0
Longitude: 0.0
Altitude: 0.0
```

i have checked my gpsHat logfile and I can see that i get the gps cordinate from the gps reciver:

```
2022-05-09 19:57:28,604 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Sent to hat: AT+CGNSINF

2022-05-09 19:57:28,705 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: AT+CGNSINF
2022-05-09 19:57:28,715 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: +CGNSINF: 1,1,20220509175728.000,60.502652,15.313006,101.952,0.00,0.0,1,,0.7,1.0,0.7,,13,16,,,46,,
2022-05-09 19:57:28,715 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - New GPS Data:
2022-05-09 19:57:28,717 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: OK
2022-05-09 19:57:28,717 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Lock Off
2022-05-09 19:57:29,419 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Sent to hat: AT+CPMS="SM"

2022-05-09 19:57:29,521 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: AT+CPMS="SM"
2022-05-09 19:57:29,523 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: +CPMS: 0,30,0,30,0,30
2022-05-09 19:57:29,524 - gsmHat.gsmHat - DEBUG - Received Data: OK
```

Someone that has this problem to or know how to do to fix it?
aother things like SMS function works but not my the GPSObj code
running on a raspberry pie zero 2 w with latest raspian lite

Update:

It is so strange, In Minicom i can use all AT-commands and they works, but when i try to use them thru serial commands  in my code the just comes up in the terminal as plain text  here is the code

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",115200) #ttyS0 is the port on the Pi3, it may be ttyAMA0 on the older Pi's
ser.flushInput()      #clear the input buffer
ser.flushOutput()     #clear the output buffer
ser.timeout = 5       #set the timeout on the serial port to 5 seconds

ReadSMS = 'AT+SMGR=1' #AT command that will show last recived SMS

ser.write(ReadSMS.encode())   #send the AT command
str = ser.readline()  #read a line of data from the serial port
print(str)           #print the response from the SIM868 chip
```

Comment: Is GPS module embedded into GSM module? Which GSM module is that? E.g. SIM7080 does not allow simultaneous LTE and GPS communication.

Comment: it is the SIM808 module and this hat:
https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm

but i am not try to run the LTE services and gps simultaneous, i just try to get the gps data from the gsmHat libs that is installed

Comment: @swevrs: But it is easy to create your own text file to store the GPS data for later processing.

Comment: @tlfong01 That is my problem. in The gsmHat lib the object 'GpsObj' that should store all The gps info. don't store any data, So That is The main problem for me

Comment: Looking into your logs... If they are correct, then the hardware returns the coordinates and this is NOT a HAT problem. This is the software library problem. The title probably needs an update.

Comment: @swevrs: (1) Yes, I very much agree with #Tomas that there is no problem with the hat. (2) After "gsm = GSMHat('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)", the HAT can now talk standard serial.  In other wordss you don't need "GPSObj = gsm.GetActualGPS()", but just use standard Rx/Tx@115200 serial commands to get the GPS data and immediately write it to your created text file.

Comment: I found out That to yesterday,  i can send sms from The mini om software to my phone, but i have tried to send with serial.write() the AT+CGPSINF to get the gps info with  serial.readline(). But only writes it out in The terminal. Just the plain AT command returns with a OK as it should but no other of the AT comands work

Comment: @swervs: (1) You said: "the plain AT command returns with a OK as it should but no other of the AT commands work". (2) I am not surprised. In the last couple of years I talked with SIM8xx. SIM76xx users and concluded/confirmed that the SIM800/7600 user spec is not 100% correct. So I usually gave up and wait for later generations. (3) Right now I am exploring new SIMCOM products including the following: (a) Start IoT connectivity story with ***SIMCom in 5G***, (b) ***SIM8905*** in smart home care assistant for seniors SIMCom has been fully committed to 2G, 3G, 4G, 5G, ...

Comment: But it is so strange, the gpsHat lib That i installed makes the sending and reciving AT commands in The logfile, where the gps location is recivied,. And when i look at the code i try the same codes but i dont recive the same results 